# HTML and CSS Window Layout Design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am facing a problem to design a window layout, here is my sample code and my problem is graphically represented thanks.

[N.B]: Window layout will be draggable and resizable, I will maintain this by using jquery later.

**Problem**
[image]

**SAMPLE CODE**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          </div>
          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li id="li-home" class="active">
                <a href="#">Home                                     <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li id="li-contact">
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown                                     <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Another action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown                                     <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Another action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid main-container">
      <div class="window">
        <div class="window-header" data-dismiss="window-dblclick">
          <div class="window-title-bar">
            <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
            <span class="window-title">window Title</span>
          </div>
          <div class="window-custom-title"></div>
          <div class="window-actions">
            <a href="#" class="window-action btn-min" data-dismiss="window-minimize" aria-hidden="true">
              <span class="fa fa-minus" title="Minimize"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="window-action btn-max" data-dismiss="window-maximize" aria-hidden="true">
              <span data-maximize="maximize" class="fa fa-square-o" title="Maximize"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="window-action btn-close" data-dismiss="window" aria-hidden="true">
              <span class="fa fa-close" title="Close"></span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="window-body"></div>
        <div class="window-footer">
          <a>link</a>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="resize-handle resize-n"></div>
            <div class="resize-handle resize-e"></div>
            <div class="resize-handle resize-s"></div>
            <div class="resize-handle resize-w"></div>
            <div class="resize-handle resize-se"></div>
            <div class="resize-handle resize-sw"></div>
            <div class="resize-handle resize-ne"></div>
            <div class="resize-handle resize-nw"></div>-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
          <div id="windowPane"></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.main-container {
  background-color: #888888;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.full-window {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  min-width: 120px !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 1049;
}
.window {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  outline: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  min-width: 240px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  resize: none;
}
.window.active > .window-header > .window-title {
  color: #428bca;
}
.window > .window-header {
  position: relative;
  cursor: move;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #e5e5e5;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
}
.window > .window-header > .window-title-bar {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  display: table-cell;
  float: left !important;
  color: #fff;
}
.window > .window-header > .window-title-bar > i {
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
.window > .window-header > .window-custom-title {
  display: table-cell;
}
.window > .window-header > .window-actions {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  display: table-cell;
  float: right !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.window > .window-header > .window-actions > .window-action {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
}
.window > .window-header > .window-actions > .window-action.btn-min,
.window > .window-header > .window-actions > .window-action.btn-max {
  background: #f0f9ff;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0f9ff 0%, #0c0a0a 47%, #f0f9ff 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f0f9ff), color-stop(47%, #0c0a0a), color-stop(100%, #f0f9ff));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f0f9ff 0%, #0c0a0a 47%, #f0f9ff 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f0f9ff 0%, #0c0a0a 47%, #f0f9ff 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f0f9ff 0%, #0c0a0a 47%, #f0f9ff 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0f9ff 0%, #0c0a0a 47%, #f0f9ff 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f0f9ff', endColorstr='#f0f9ff', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  padding: 1px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
.window > .window-header > .window-actions > .window-action.btn-min: hover, .window > .window-header > .window-actions > .window-action.btn-max: hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 151px -50px #00cef2;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 151px -50px #00cef2;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 151px -50px #00cef2;
}
.window > .window-header > .window-actions > .window-action.btn-close {
  background: #e78677;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e78677 0%, #c44205 50%, #c01e03 51%, #e17225 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #e78677), color-stop(50%, #c44205), color-stop(51%, #c01e03), color-stop(100%, #e17225));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e78677 0%, #c44205 50%, #c01e03 51%, #e17225 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e78677 0%, #c44205 50%, #c01e03 51%, #e17225 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e78677 0%, #c44205 50%, #c01e03 51%, #e17225 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e78677 0%, #c44205 50%, #c01e03 51%, #e17225 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e78677', endColorstr='#e17225', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.window > .window-header > .window-actions > .window-action.btn-close: hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 151px -50px #fcffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 151px -50px #fcffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 151px -50px #fcffff;
}
.window > .window-body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.window > .window-footer {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 16.428571429px;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
}
.window > .resize-handle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 6px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  zoom: 1;
  display: block;
}
.window > .resize-n {
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  cursor: n-resize;
}
.window > .resize-e {
  top: 0;
  right: -3px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: e-resize;
}
.window > .resize-s {
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  cursor: s-resize;
}
.window > .resize-w {
  top: 0;
  left: -3px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: w-resize;
}
.window > .resize-sw {
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  cursor: sw-resize;
}
.window > .resize-ne {
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  cursor: ne-resize;
}
.window > .resize-nw {
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  cursor: nw-resize;
}
.window.ns-resize {
  cursor: ns-resize;
}
.window.ew-resize {
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
.disable-shade {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  display: none;
}
.disable-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.disable-select {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.window-pane {
  z-index: 999;
}
.window-pane .label {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.window-pane .label .close {
  float: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
.window-pane .label + .label {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=window.css.map */
```

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/DzZPUEmL3A13J6Pfs5CE?p=preview)**

Comment: the floating elements (I believe) is the cause for this. Look up 'clearfix'. You might also benefit from learning css specificity and that way you could remove all those horrible !important tags ;)

Comment: @jbutler483, can you update my plunker?

Answer (score 1):

You can relpace your css for `.window > .window-body` with this

```
.window > .window-body {
position: relative;
min-height:100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
border: 5px solid #000;
background-color: #fff;
}
```

bcoz the problem is due to `margin: 0 5px 0 5px;` as it is occupying extra space so, you can give the same design by including a `border: 5px solid #000;

Comment: Solution is good, but this is not fair, when i use firebug, the body element is not holded into window.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add these 2 properties to

```
.window > .window-footer {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 16.428571429px;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 25px; // new
  height: 25px; // new
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not perfect solution, window body is not contained int window, it is gone over.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/u8uqqexa/)

I just changed the following CSS part:

```
.window > .window-body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 295px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0 5px 0px 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Seemed like you were spending some pixels on borders and margins.

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/FPkglpacd55njkoZUyBy?p=preview)

Comment: can you give me any plunker? i want to fit  window-body based on window.

Comment: window-body is inside window. You could use `  min-height: 92%;` to achieve the same, I believe.

Comment: I have added the plunker link. Hope it helps.

Comment: Why will i use 92% min-height?, i want fit 100%.